# Putting the name on Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a canvas on my web page that will let the users type their name in "Journal" font.  I have the following code, but, as you can see in dokeyDown, I can only type  "Z". How can I make it for all the alphabets so that users can type their full name. Do I need to specify keyId for each alphabet or is their any easier way? Below is what I have

```
<div id="my_painter">
    <canvas id="canvas" tabindex="0"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var tempContext = null;
    window.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        console.log(canvas.parentNode.clientWidth);
        canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.clientHeight;        
        tempContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
        tempContext.fillStyle = "blue";
        tempContext.font = "20px Journal";
        canvas.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
        canvas.focus();        
        window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
       
    }

function doKeyDown(e) {
        var keyID = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keyID === 90) {
            tempContext.fillText("A", 100, 60);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This will allow you to show any character

Instead of extracting the `.keyCode`, get the `.key`, which is the character itself. Then you can display that character easily.

To allow a series of characters to show, you will want to move the cursor right at each step, e.g. by advancing it by a few pixels each time.

For this to work well, you are better off *not* using Journal, but rather choosing a monospaced font such as `Courier New`.

```js
var tempContext = null;
var x = 100
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  console.log(canvas.parentNode.clientWidth);
  canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.clientHeight;
  tempContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  tempContext.fillStyle = "blue";
  tempContext.font = "20px Journal";

  canvas.focus();
  window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);

}

function doKeyDown(e) {

  tempContext.fillText(e.key, x, 60);
  x += 9
  e.preventDefault();

}
```

```html
<div id="my_painter">
  <canvas id="canvas" tabindex="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: If I mistype any character, the backspace key is not working.

Comment: If you want to provide text entry in general, this is a _terrible_ way to do it! You will keep discovering things that you need to add: capitals, newlines, other character sets, etc etc. That is why there are specialised tools to enter text: to avoid reinventing the wheel, painfully.

Comment: can you please point me to some specialized tools. Paid or free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.fromCharCode()` method to convert the keyID variable into a character. In that way, you don't need to match the code for each key.

A listener on canvas is already added so I commented on the listener on the window otherwise every character will get printed twice.

```js
var tempContext = null;
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.clientHeight;
  tempContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  tempContext.fillStyle = "blue";
  tempContext.font = "20px Journal";
  canvas.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
  canvas.focus();
  // window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);

}

var x_pos = 100;

function doKeyDown(e) {
  var keyID = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var character = String.fromCharCode(keyID);
  tempContext.fillText(character, x_pos, 60);
  x_pos += 15; // Add space between letters
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div id="my_painter">
    <canvas id="canvas" tabindex="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Neha Soni,
It is typing the same character at the same place so the characters are overlapping each other. Is their any way, this can be prevented. If I want to type Anjali, it will overlap Anjali. I want to type each character separately not one character at one time.

Comment: I updated the answer by giving space between each character. Can you please try now?

Comment: It works fine. How can I reduce the space between characters and also when i click on backspace key to delete any character, it creates boxes instead of deleting the words that I mistyped. It does the same thing for space bar key.

Comment: To reduce the space between characters you can play with the `x_pos` variable. Adjust its value according to your needs.

Comment: I tried to play around with x_pos. the space between the characters is not changing.

Comment: I tried to make x_pos =1 and also tried x_pos=500. In both the cases, the space was exactly same

Comment: In the above answer, the xpos is incremented by 20 points. Try changing that. When you decrease the 20 to 10 or 5 the characters will get close.

Comment: for some reason, the characters are not getting closer. i even tried to change the font family. I upvoted your answer. I will post a separate question for backspace key. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: See the updated answer, the characters are close now.